# Stop Netbeans Beeping

Tags: netbeans

On Windows 7, when I keep pressing Ctrl+S on  a file that's already saved, the Windows error sound will  play.

This is very annoying, and is quite distracting when i am in the habit of continually pressing Ctrl+S during work.

Is there a way to disable this annoying `features`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in NetBeans IDE, not allowed invocation of "SaveAction" from a user macro, like this keymap override "Ctrl-S" with:

> " " delete-previous save

This means that there is **no way to prevent than the OS sends an sound-error**, 
But reading about it, it seems that other users complain about this behavior and have now been presented several solutions to enable a future we can customize these behaviors.

You can read more about this [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203979)

The only solution I can think of is to disable the sound system-error.

Answer (score 3):

Well! This might help someone (may be begginer) in getting rid of this annoying Beep. Following this will help you disable Windows Default Beep. So, you won't hear this beep at all even outside netBeans.

```
1) Go to Control Panel.
2) Click Sound.
3) Click on Sounds in Top Tab Menu.
4) Click on Default Beep from Program Events Sounds List. 
5) Select "None" from the drop down Sounds list.
6) Click Apply.
```

Comment: whenever i have my head phones plugged in and Netbeans causes a "ding", it sends the music to the laptop speakers for a moment while playing the "ding" through headphones... ridiculous. your solution solves an area of great frustration for me, THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, to disable the hardware speaker beep system-wide:

```sh
xset b off
```