# Netbeans 12.6 editor not allowing me to type a lower case s

Tags: java, netbeans

I am not expecting anyone to know the answer to this question but I thought I would try. When I am in Netbeans and typing in code it won't let me type a lower case s. It beeps at me. I can copy and paste an s without a problem. I have rebooted and it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: key works in other programs/apps? upper case `S` works!? (now i am confused!!xDxD)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041853/stop-netbeans-beeping Are you certian that the 'ctrl' key is not stuck in a pressed down state, or that you have some macro or hot key application that is misbehaving? And out of interest, which OS are you using? And just in case, have you tried a different keyboard (or plugged in an external one if using a laptop)?

Comment: These are all good suggestions. I will try them out. I am using Windows 10 w/ latest patches.

Comment: A strange problem. [1] It's trivial to use **Tools > Options > Keymap** to map a keyboard shortcut to a specific action in NetBeans (e.g. The shortcut `Ctrl+s` maps to the action **File > Save**), so that might explain your problem. That said, I don't see how you could map the character 's' as a shortcut to the action "beep". [2] Does this issue only occur when typing in the edit window, or does it permeate NetBeans? For example, what happens if you create and save a file containing the character 's'? Do you get a beep? If not then the problem is obviously specific to the edit window...

Comment: ... [3] Also, press 's' to provoke the beep, then navigate to **View > IDE Log**. Anything of interest logged? [4] It is safe to instantiate a second installation of NetBeans 12.6 temporarily in some other directory from a zip file, being careful not to import existing settings. That won't impact your existing installation. If you do that, does the problem also occur in your new installation? If not then you know that the issue is specific to your older installation, and you can use the new one instead. That approach wouldn't explain **_why_** you got the problem, but it might resolve it.

Comment: I tried plugging in a different keyboard but it still has the problem. Saving a file containing the character 's' works. I can't see a keyboard shortcut mapped to 's'. It seems to be specific to the edit window.

Comment: OK, so hardware is clearly not an issue, and the beep only occurs in the NetBeans edit window. A really unusual problem! As stated in my previous comment, if there is nothing written to the log file after pressing 's' my only suggestion is to set up a second NetBeans 12.6 installation to see if the problem goes away. Of course you could simply reinstall NetBeans 12.6, but that seems unnecessarily drastic unless you are completely stuck.

Comment: I reinstalled Netbeans 12.6 and it didn't help. I have a 12.5 installation still. The same thing happens when I run 12.5.

Comment: Here is the log entry after I pressed 's'.

Comment: WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.XMLDataObject@3b2899bf[MultiFileObject@22943189[Actions/Help/master-help.xml]]

Comment: So it looks like it is a problem with a "Invalid shortcut". I will look into it further.